# VBA Excel getting last child of a table

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to scrape data from a website that has a constantly changing table, and i would like to get the last children data from said table, i tried searching online and testing with some codes such as

```
oElement(1).children(n).innerText
```

as well as

```
oElement(1).lastChild.innerText
```

but to no avail, how can i do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: i did, doesn't work, object required it says

Answer (score 1):

Use the `length` property of the `children` collection to access the last element:

```
With oElement(1).children
    MsgBox .item(.length - 1).innerText
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

So i've found out a way, which is to do a loop until its null or nothing then take the previous entry,

```
i = 0
Do Until oElement(4).Children(i) = "" Or Null
    If oElement(4).Children(i) <> "" Then
    i = i + 1
    End If
Loop
Debug.print oElement(4).children(i - 1)
```

worked for me, but if anyone have a less tedious and straight forward answer, please do comment :)